# MomentJS change the format from YYYYMMDD

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I have this format of date YY which looks like `20141229` I'm trying to get it into Timestamp format
I tried `moment(date).format('x')` but I get "Invalid date", not sure how to make this done, any help please ?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

moment constructor takes format as second parameter, so `moment('20141229', 'YYYYMMDD')` will give you valid moment object. and calling `.unix()` should give you timestamp.

[Docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Answer (score 1):

Try separating segments with a space, for example

```
var date = "2014 12 29"
var stamp = moment(date).format("x")
```